# free online tool for business users to modify database dimensions

Tags: data-warehouse, business-intelligence

is there any free or good paid tools to allow business users to edit data warehouse dimensions and then initiate updates to related tables?

Looking for a really simple one solution. One example, is to let business users change Product dimension so they can assign/change Product Category or Price.

I am on SQL Server 2008R2

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention that important piece :) I have updated my question

Comment: In a recent implementation I built my own in a MS Acess ADP file. I have done some investigation on Talend (a free tool) but it is very complicated. I am also looking for a tool to do this but the fact is it isn't a trivial exercise when you have to start splitting SCD2 records and backloading fact tables for backdated changes.

Comment: this is actually very interesting idea to use Access for that. Can you share some screenshots of what you built? I might accept it as a best answers since I was not able to find anything else.

Comment: I'm unable to get a screenshot at the moment. You can use any tool but an ADP is the quickest way I know of to get database tables in front of a user with a bit of VBA validation. It is just used to add new config entries then calls stored procedures to apply this to the correct tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as an example about back applying: when the user changes a product price they may wish to back date it. This requires the following changes:

1. Create a new dimension record (assuming this is an SCD2), generating a new surrogate key with a start/end date
2. Replace the old surrogate key in the fact with the new surrogate key from the effective date

So this is at the very least a two step process which I wrap up in a stored procedure called by the ADP

Again all the usual suspects (Microsoft, IBM etc,) have what they call MDM tools, but they are all really complicated, requiring definition of a business model (which is fair enough)